# How to find all overlapping ranges and partition them into chunks?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array of ranges and I want to be able to find all the overlapping ranges:

#### For example:

```
var examples = [
    // Group 1
    {start: 9, end: 10.50},       // Range 1
    {start: 10, end: 10.50},      // Range 5

    // Group 2
    {start: 11, end: 13},         // Range 2
    {start: 13.5, end: 14.5},     // Range 3
    {start: 11.5, end: 14}        // Range 4
]
```

1. Range 2 overlaps with Range 4
2. Range 3 overlaps with Range 4
3. Although Range 2 does not overlap with Range 3, because they both overlap with Range 4. They will be put into the same group
4. Range 1 and Range 5 only overlap with each other and so they will be in their own group

#### JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jukufon7/2/

Comment: Are the ranges inclusive or exclusive? In other words, if we have {start:9, end:10} and {start:10,end:11}, is that two separate groups or do we consider that they overlap at the single value 10?

Comment: @rici Exclusive. The example you gave should be considered to be two groups!

Comment: the difference is whether the comparison in step 5.1 of the algorithm I propose is `<` or `<=`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Here's my take:**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lavq4xn9/)

```
var examples = [
    {start: 17, end: 20},
    {start: 9, end: 10.50},
    {start: 15, end: 17},
    {start: 11, end: 12},
    {start: 18, end: 19.5},
    {start: 19.5, end: 22},
    {start: 11.5, end: 12.5},
    {start: 11.5, end: 13},
    {start: 17.5, end: 18.5},
    {start: 19, end: 19.5},
    {start: 22, end: 25}
]

function partitionIntoOverlappingRanges(array) {
  array.sort(function (a,b) {
    if (a.start < b.start)
      return -1;
    if (a.start > b.start)
      return 1;
    return 0;
  });
  var getMaxEnd = function(array) {
    if (array.length==0) return false;
    array.sort(function (a,b) {
      if (a.end < b.end)
        return 1;
      if (a.end > b.end)
        return -1;
      return 0;
    });
    return array[0].end;    
  };
  var rarray=[];
  var g=0;
  rarray[g]=[array[0]];

  for (var i=1,l=array.length;i<l;i++) {
    if ( (array[i].start>=array[i-1].start)
         &&
         (array[i].start<getMaxEnd(rarray[g]))
    ) {    
      rarray[g].push(array[i]);
    } else {
      g++;   
      rarray[g]=[array[i]];
    }
  }
  return rarray;
} // end partitionIntoOverlappingRanges
```

**Results from `examples` above:**

[image: results]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple scanning algorithm. It executes in O(n log n) because of the necessity to sort the ranges.

The basic idea is to just scan from left to right looking for both start and end points (which requires a sorted list of each of those). While scanning, keep track of the number of active ranges (that is, ranges whose start point has been encountered and whose endpoint has not yet been encountered). Every time you hit a start-point, the range needs to be added to the current group. The range count is maintained by incrementing it at each start point and decrementing it at each end point. Every time the count returns to 0, a complete group has been found.

If you want to compute the simplified set of ranges instead of the groups, you can simplify. Instead of keeping a set of ranges in a group, the start point of the current composed group is set when the active range count increments from 0 to 1, and the end point is set when the active range count decrements from 1 to 0. In this case, you only need a sorted list of start points and a sorted list of end points (in the algorithm as presented, the sorted start points are found by sorting the ranges themselves by start point. The group is needed so that the range can be added to the accumulated group.)

1. Sort the ranges by their start values.
2. Make a list of the end values, and sort it (it's not necessary to know which range belongs to an endpoint). Call this end_values.
3. Initialize current_group to an empty set, and active_range_count to 0. Initialize current_range and current_end to 0.
4. Loop until done:

   1. If current_range is a valid index into ranges and ranges[current_range].start is less than end_values[current_end]:

      - Add ranges[current_range] to current_group, increment current_range and increment active_range_count.
      - Loop.
   2. Otherwise, if current_end is a valid index into end_values:

      - Decrement active_range_count and increment current_end.
      - If active_range_count is 0, then current_group is complete; save it, and reinitialize current_group to an empty set.
      - Loop.
   3. Otherwise, done.

Here are both versions in javascript:

```
/* Partition an array of ranges into non-overlapping groups */
/* Side-effect: sorts the array */
function partition(ranges) {
  var end_values = ranges.map(function(r){return r.end}).sort(function(a, b){return a - b})
  ranges.sort(function(a, b){return a.start - b.start})
  var i = 0, j = 0, n = ranges.length, active = 0
  var groups = [], cur = []
  while (1) {
    if (i < n && ranges[i].start < end_values[j]) {
      cur.push(ranges[i++])
      ++active
    } else if (j < n) {
      ++j  
      if (--active == 0) {
        groups.push(cur)
        cur = [] 
      }    
    } else break   
  }
  return groups
}

/* Given a array of possibly overlapping ranges, produces
 * an array of non-overlapping ranges covering the same
 * values.
 */
function compose_ranges(ranges) {
  var starts = ranges.map(function(r){return r.start}).sort(function(a, b){return a - b})
  var ends = ranges.map(function(r){return r.end}).sort(function(a, b){return a - b})
  var i = 0, j = 0, n = ranges.length, active = 0
  var combined = []
  while (1) {
    if (i < n && starts[i] < ends[j]) {
      if (active++ == 0) combined.push({start: starts[i]})
      ++i
    } else if (j < n) {
      if (--active == 0) combined[combined.length - 1].end = ends[j]
      ++j
    } else break;
  } 
  return combined
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If writing actual code is too time consuming, do you mind writing some pseudo code? I am a bit confused by the answer. (e.g. I have read your answer a few times and I still don't understand why we need an array of end_values) - Amongst a few other things that I am not quite getting the grasp of

Comment: @samol: I added a bit of explanation. The above is pseudocode :)

Comment: What is "ranges[current_range].start == scan_value", Where was this scan_value initialized?

Comment: @samol: I forgot to delete that unnecessary initialization. When I first typed the algo, I used an explicut scan value for what i thought would be didactic, but I reconsidered. Sorry. Its fixed now.

Comment: @samol: And now in javascript, in which I'm not an expert. But it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is simple: record the max range of every certain group.

Give a shot to the code below.

```
function contains(range, number) {
    return number > range.start && number < range.end
}


function partitionIntoOverlappingRanges(array) {
    var groups = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < groups.length; j++) {
            if (contains(groups[j], array[i].start) || contains(groups[j], array[i].end)) {
                groups[j].arrays.push(array[i]);
                if (groups[j].start > array[i].start) groups[j].start = array[i].start;
                if (groups[j].end < array[i].end) groups[j].end = array[i].end;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (j == groups.length) {
            groups.push({
                start: array[i].start,
                end: array[i].end,
                arrays: [array[i]]
            })
        }
    }
    return groups
}
```

Comment: I think this might be wrong. It might need to assume that the ranges are already sorted (which it is not). I ran a few test cases with this, with randomly shuffled ranges and it produces incorrect results. Otherwise, if we sort the array first, I think it will produce the correct results :) Thank you

Comment: @samol Sorry, you're right. I just used the example you gave on *jsfiddle*, assuming all the others are sorted.