# Javascript - Check numeric range overlapping in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, range, overlapping

I have an array of time ranges with start & end values.

```
var timeRanges = [{
    start: 120,
    end: 140
},{
    start: 180,
    end: 220
},{
    start: 250,
    end: 300
}]
```

Need to check whether the selected range overlap the time range or not. And also the selected range should be in between the timeRange intervals. (Ex: 140-180, 220-250)

```
var selected = {
    start: 150,
    end: 170
}
```

Comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30472556/how-to-find-all-overlapping-ranges-and-partition-them-into-chunks/30473019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your time ranges are sorted, this solution will work. Otherwise, you need to implement time range sorting as well.

```
function isValidRange(timeRanges, selectedRange) {
var isValid = true;
var minStart = timeRanges[0].start;
var maxEnd = timeRanges[timeRanges.length - 1].end;

if(selectedRange.start < selectedRange.end && selectedRange.start > minStart && selectedRange.end < maxEnd) {
    for(var i=0; i<timeRanges.length; i++) {
        if((selectedRange.start >= timeRanges[i].start && selectedRange.start <= timeRanges[i].end)
        || (selectedRange.end >= timeRanges[i].start && selectedRange.end <= timeRanges[i].end)) {
            isValid = false;
            break;
        }
        else if(i != timeRanges.length - 1) {
            if(selectedRange.start > timeRanges[i].end && selectedRange.start < timeRanges[i+1].start) {
                if(selectedRange.end < timeRanges[i+1].start) {
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    isValid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    isValid = false;
}
return isValid;
}

var timeRanges = [{
    start: 120,
    end: 140
},{
    start: 180,
    end: 220
},{
    start: 250,
    end: 300
}];

var selected = {
    start: 141,
    end: 222
};

alert(isValidRange(timeRanges, selected));
```

Answer (score 14):

Time interval `B` 'overlaps' `A` if:

- `B` starts after `A` starts but before `A` finishes.
- `B` starts before `A` starts and finishes after `A` starts.

So you can write a function which decides exactly that.

```
function areOverlapping(A, B) {
    if(B.start < A.start) {
        return B.finish > A.start;
    }
    else {
        return B.start < A.finish;
    }
}
```

Comment: ....or, more concisely, `const areOverlapping = (a, b) => b.start < a.start ? b.finish > a.start : b.start < a.finish;`

Answer (score 8):

```
 const overlaps = timeRanges.some( range => 
  (range.start < selected.start && range.end > selected.start) || 
  (range.start < selected.end && range.end > selected.end) || 
  (range.start > selected.start && range.end < selected.end)
 );
```

Comment: It doesn't cover the case when `selected` is wider than `range` (ie, `range` is contained in `selected`).
 `|| (range.start > selected.start && range.end < selected.end)` should be added.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run your selection through the array and calculate what you need?

```
timeRanges.forEach(function(aRange, index)) {

   if (selected.start > aRange.start && selected.end < aRange.end)
      console.log('Selection falls within the item ' + index):


}
```